# Can noahide do netilat yadayim?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, netilat-yadayim-washing

I wanted to ask about the halacha of noahide based on tradition of orthodox, that according to some sources, a noahide was refrain from some blessing which required "asher kidshanu" which because Noahide is not part of the house of Israel. But how about netilat yadayim, i mean we need to dispose the impurities to serve G-d. Is it still forbidden for Noahide ? If yes is there any solutions for this ?